# Displaying a list on a JSP page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have been working on a web application and need to display values on a JSP related to a Full Response class I have created.  The FullResponse class is below...

```
public class FullResponse {

    Double total_hits;
    Double max_score;
    List<Hits> hits;

    public FullResponse(){

    }

    public Double getTotal_hits() {
        return total_hits;
    }

    public void setTotal_hits(Double total_hits) {
        this.total_hits = total_hits;
    }

    public Double getMax_score() {
        return max_score;
    }

    public void setMax_score(Double max_score) {
        this.max_score = max_score;
    }

    public List<Hits> getHits() {
        return hits;
    }

    public void setHits(List<Hits> hits) {
        this.hits = hits;
    }

}
```

The Hits class is as follows...

```
public class Hits {

       String _index;
       String _type;
       String _id;
       Double _score;
       Fields fields;

public Hits(){

       }

public String get_index() {
        return _index;
    }

    public void set_index(String _index) {
        this._index = _index;
    }

    public String get_type() {
        return _type;
    }

    public void set_type(String _type) {
        this._type = _type;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public Double get_score() {
        return _score;
    }

    public void set_score(Double _score) {
        this._score = _score;
    }

    public Fields getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    public void setFields(Fields fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }


}
```

And the fields class is as follows...

```
public class Fields {

    String item_name;

    public Fields(){

    }

    public String getName(){
        return item_name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        item_name=name;
    }
}
```

Within my controller I am passing my model a FullResponse, which is name "products" that contains 6 hits.  Using these hits I need to display the names of the products and a button to select a product based on the ID. How can I cycle through the list and display these names with the corresponding buttons.  I am unfamiliar with JSP pages and dont know how to cycle through the list of hits.  Someone please help, this assignment is way over my head.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lookup")
public String look(ModelMap model,
        @RequestParam(value="find", required=true) String find,
        HttpSession session,
        Principal principal) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

    String user = principal.getName();
    model.addAttribute("products", database.getProducts(user));
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    CallSearch test=new CallSearch(find);
    FullResponse test1 = test.search();
    model.addAttribute("products", test1);

    return "productlookup";
```

"productlookup" is obviously the name of my JSP page that I would like to display this information on.  I have the core of the page created but I dont know how to use this "products" attribute and display each hit.

```
<table border="border" align="center">
    <caption>What's in the Fridge?</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="hit" items="${products.hits}">
            <th>${hit.fields.name}</th>
            <th><a href="productlookup?id=${product.id}"><span class="label   label-danger" >select</span></a></th>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Today is the first time I have used this site so I am just learning about the upvoting and other capabilities but I will make sure to do that.  I am getting it to cycle through the results but I cant get the name to show up.  I have tried several different calls but the name never shows up.  I know it is cycling through because I am getting 6 rows to my table with the buttons.

Comment: Note that you are overwriting the attribute with key `products`.

Comment: I guess I am confused on what you are saying about overwriting the attribute with key "products"

Comment: In your handler method, you were doing `model.addAttribute("products", ...` with two different objects, the second one overwriting the first one.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but I still cant get the name to appear and it is the last thing that I need to have done.  Im still having trouble referring to each attribute because there are lists within each class which is throwing me off.

Comment: I would check if that field actually has a value by debugging while in the controller handler method. Or use a logger to output the value and see that it is not empty.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am getting null values within my hit responses so that is where my issue is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `forEach` here: [jstl](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

Use `var` for the current variable selected in loop and `items` for the list.
Ex:

```
<c:forEach var="hit" items="${products.hits}">  ${hit.name} //print name </c:forEach>
```

Don't forget to import the taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Try to follow the Java conventions in naming class attributes and getters and setters, it will be easier when you use JSP pages and beans.